# ¿Que recurso puedo utilizar para convertir una planilla de cálculo de google a un formato json?

Tags: javascript, json, excel, google-hoja-de-cálculo, scraping

Muy buenos días estimados!!

Estoy con un desafío en el cuál tengo un archivo con formato de planilla de cálculos de google y para poder manipular y/o usar estos datos en Javascript al menos me imaginaba convertirlos a un formato JSON y veo que en la web hay sitios que realizan estas conversiones gratis, incluso el mismo google tiene la opción de guardarlo en formatos tsv y csv que aparentan parecerse al json para luego refactorizarlo con ingenio con código propio y ya entro en un terreno nuevo sin aparentes antecedentes ni práctica en el mismo, o en el mejor de los casos si existen bibliotecas confiables que parsean un archivo csv o tsv a json, veo algunas extensiones de vsc que aparentan hacer algo si saber si son fiables.

Mi consulta se orienta a la fiabilidad de las conversiones pues la planilla tiene miles de celdas las cuales ni voy a comprobar si hay coincidencia de datos pues pragmáticamente sería ineficiente hacerlo.

Soy principiante en esta búsqueda de estos recursos para avanzar en la práctica en programación al menos con javascrip.

Hago un breve resumen para el objetivo de mi desafío, es contrastar la data de esta planilla con los precios reales de un producto específico de las webs que figuran en la planilla, si hay discrepancias dar un alerta y en los mejores de los casos sugerir o corregir esos precios incorrectos.

De lo poco que estuve viendo existen sitios que se encargan de este trabajo y yo quiero lograrlo al menos con código propio o iniciarme en el concepto del funcionamiento de los recursos existentes en materia de estudio de mercado en precios.

Saludos colegas y hasta la próxima!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El json puedes obtenerlo manualmente con los siguientes pasos

1. el link de la plantilla (debe ser público sino no funciona este método)

Ej: Un link de plantilla se ve así
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{{id](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%7B%7Bid) del documento}}/edit{{etc etc}}

2. lo modificas de esta forma para obtener el pseudo json ( gid=0 es la primera hoja, gid=1 es la 2da hoja, etc)

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{{id](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%7B%7Bid) del documento}}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&gid=0

3. Se descargará un archivo json.txt

A este archivo debes eliminar una parte del inicio y una parte del final

inicio: /*O_o*/
google.visualization.Query.setResponse(

final: );

4. Entonces ya tienes tu json

También puedes generar un código para hacer esto de forma más automática si es que lo necesitas.

Comment: Gracias Claudio, lo realicé en la barra del navegador y nada entregó, esperaba incluso una descarga, está en modo público el link que generé de la palnilla, tal vez hay un paso que me falta comprender. yo en principio al link público le agregué la extensión que me pasaste como /gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&gid=0 y nada

Comment: Disculpas, era borrar el final de la url donde terminaba el id del link, ahí funcionó agregando la extensión que me pasaste!! gracias

Comment: Claudio gracias a tu ayuda estoy avanzando con el json, es claro y entendible lo que me retornó, ahora tal vez sepas como volver a transformar este json en una planilla de google tal vez? pues al actualizar este json voy a agregar campos para retornar determinados valores procesados y poder visualizarlos fuera de un formato json. ¿Tu crees que es posible? gracias por la atención , Saludos!